# Updating a variable & adding numbers to two different lists

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

I have just started doing threading this week and I'm kind of stuck on one of the exercises.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    public class RandomNumberConsumer implements Runnable {

    ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> numbersProduced;

    public RandomNumberConsumer(ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> numbersProduced) {
        this.numbersProduced = numbersProduced;
    }
    //Should eventually hold the sum of all random number consumed
    int sumTotal = 0;
    List<Integer> below50 = new ArrayList();
    List<Integer> aboveOr50 = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //In this exercise, we start four threads, each producing 100 numbers, so we know how much to consume
        for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("first" + numbersProduced.take());
                System.out.println("second" + numbersProduced.take());
                 System.out.println("third" + numbersProduced.take());
                 System.out.println("fourth" + numbersProduced.take());

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(RandomNumberConsumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }

    public int getSumTotal() {
        return sumTotal;
    }

    public List<Integer> getBelow50() {
        return below50;
    }

    public List<Integer> getAboveOr50() {
        return aboveOr50;
    }

}
```

Basically what I don't understand is how to update sumTotal variable to show all consumed random numbers since they're stored in ArrayBlockingQueue<> and also how to insert them into either the below 50 or above Or 50 Lists.

Comment: Which thread is filling ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> numbersProduced ?

Comment: I have a class called RandomNumberProduced which does the filling: public void run() {
    try{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBERS_TO_PRODUCE; i++) {
      int random = (int) ((Math.random() * MAX_RANDOM+1));
        numbersProduced.put(random);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        numbersProduced.put(random);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        numbersProduced.put(random);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        numbersProduced.put(random);
        Thread.sleep(1000); 
    }
    }catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); {
        
    }
    }
  }

Comment: can you send the problem description ?

Answer (score 0):

What about don't use numbersProduced.take() in the run method and define  a new function, even in RandomNumberConsumer class?

```
int foo() throws InterruptedException{ //because of take function
int a=numbersProduced.take();
if(a<50)
    below50.add(a);
else
    over50.add(a);
sumTotal=sumtTotal+a;
return a;
}
```

now in run call foo and not numbersProduced.take()

I must tell you, i hope you know it: if you use threads which modify the same variable you must use Semaphore or synchronized methods.

Ps: sorry for bad English :)